# Which control to use for working on data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, controls

What I want is a controller that can perform all operations on a table of a database, which includes create, delete, insert ,records edit records/update etc.
I have used all the controls:

- gridview
- datalist
- detailsview
- formview
- listview

I would like to have your opinion as to 
"which control is the best to use, easy to program, and is user friendly, simple coding all the good points."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView` is your best bet if you want Create/Read/Update/Delete operations.

The others all require a bit more work if you want to be able to perform all of the operations.

Comment: All controls are ASP.NET server-side controls so I think OP is taking about ASP.NET. So you could mean `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

Personally i've always preferred the ListView.  It will give you all the automatic Create, read, update, delete operations and think it allows for the easiest customization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom, complex UI then `FormView`.

If you have small amount of fields (2-10) - `GridView`,

If large - `DetailsView`.